# boot messages for wireless nic in Fedora 14

Tags: fedora, boot

After a recent install of Fedora 14, I had to build the firmware for my Broadcom 4311 wireless nic. I got the wireless working, but only after adding `modprobe b43` to the `rc.local` file.

On every boot, however, I am now get a message stating:

```
Bringing up interface Auto_Tigris_Connecticus:  Device  does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
[FAILED]
```

My understanding is that the `rc.local` file is loaded after the other *"normal"* boot steps, so I am thinking that the `modprobe b43` statement should be added elsewhere. Can someone point me in the right direction as to where to add module `b43` in the boot process to make sure that I don't receive these (admittedly harmless) boot messages?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a file in `/etc/modprobe.d` - something like `/etc/modprobe.d/wlan.conf` should do - whose contents look like:

```
alias wlan0 b43
```

Where `wlan0` is the name of the interface.

Comment: Ill give that a shot and post the results... Thanks

Comment: Didn't seem to work... Is there a chance it has something to do with the interface name of `Auto_Tigris_Connecticus`?? It automatically picked up the name of the ESSID of the wireless connection. Should it actually be `wlan0`?

Comment: Ηari: yes, have you tried it with `wlan0` or whatever it's name is in `/sbin/ifconfig -a` ?